Upload multiple files with optional parameter
This function is supposed to upload multiple files. I have given it 5 file parameters, out of which 2 are mandatory and the last 3 are optional:
export async function uploadMultipleFiles(page: Page, folder: string, file1: string, file2: string, file3?: string, file4?: string, file5?: string) {
    await page.locator('input[type="file"]').setInputFiles([path.join(folder, file1), path.join(folder, file2) ]);
}

If call the method with 3 file parameters, only the first two will be uploaded, those that correspond to the mandatory parameters which i declared.
await functions.uploadMultipleFiles(page, 'tests/pictures/', 'photo1.jpg', 'photo2.jpg', 'conditions.pdf');

I am to understand that if i want other optional parameter files to be uploaded i need to fill in the rest of them as such
export async function uploadMultipleFiles(page: Page, folder: string, file1: string, file2: string, file3?: string, file4?: string, file5?: string) {
    await page.locator('input[type="file"]').setInputFiles([
        path.join(folder, file1),
        path.join(folder, file2),
        path.join(folder, file3),
        path.join(folder, file4),
        path.join(folder, file5)]);
}

But if i do this, i will get an error for file 3,4 and 5
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
(parameter) file3: string | undefined

How do i use the file 3,4 and 5 parameters as long as i keep them optional ?

Like your other question, the request illustrates a few rather questionable practices and is missing context. I'm not convinced the abstractions you're trying to write are good practice or necessary. Providing more context will help avoid an xy problem so someone can offer a cleaner, more fundamental solution to your test design.

Instead of passing each file as separate parameters, you could pass it as a list of files to support any number of files:
export async function uploadMultipleFiles_2(
  page: Page, 
  folder: string, 
  files: string[]
) {
  const inputFiles = files.map((file) => path.join(folder, file));
  await page.locator('input[type="file"]').setInputFiles(inputFiles);
}

Or if you want to do it in separate parameters, using filter(Boolean) will remove undefined:
export async function uploadMultipleFiles(
  page: Page,
  folder: string,
  file1: string,
  file2: string,
  file3?: string,
  file4?: string,
  file5?: string
) {
  const inputFiles = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5]
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map((file) => path.join(folder, file));
  await page.locator('input[type="file"]').setInputFiles(files);
}


You can use the spread operator:
export async function uploadMultipleFiles(page: Page, folder: string, file1: string, file2: string, ...extraFiles: string[]) {
  const files = [path.join(folder, file1), path.join(folder, file2)];
  if (extraFiles) {
    files.push(...extraFiles.map((file) => path.join(folder, file)));
  }
  await page.locator('input[type="file"]').setInputFiles(files);

